# Laravel 5 Auth logs me out after a while when I'm logged in and active

Tags: session, authentication, basic-authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm using Larvael 5 (upgraded to 5.1, but this has been happening since before). I'll be using the site and then click on a different link and I'll be redirected to the login page.

I understand when this happens if I've been inactive for a while and the session expires, but this happens when I'm being active. For example, I created a menu and was testing that all the links were working, I clicked a few and one of them sent me to the login page. Once logged in I could click the link just fine, so I had been indeed logged out. There's no apparent pattern either.

Is this a security measure? Does the session expire regardless of activity?

Comment: not a normal behaviour. the default timeout session is 2 hours (you can look at the config/session.php; the value is in minutes). Does clicking on different items randomly sent you to the login page? Do you have a plugin in your browser called auto clear cache? If you have that, it might be the issue. How do you authenticate users, do you use the laravel out of the box Authentication? My suggestion for now is to do clean install laravel, remigrate your database and try out the laravel built in authentication. If it works, something wrong with your codes/database

Comment: if it does not work, try switch to another browser.

Comment: Yes, I'm using out of the box Authentication. My browser cache is fine. It's not so much clicking links as just trying to do something when the page hasn't been inactive too long. Like I said, I haven't found a pattern so I can't describe it easily. I'll be using the page and then I'm thrown to the login page. I don't have any code messing with login session or anything so I don't know what it could be. I was just wondering if the session normally expired two hours after authenticating regardless of activity or if someone else had encountered similar behavior.

Comment: We are facing the same problem and it seems many people do too. I've found [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172) which may be related, unfortunately there's no clue as to if this was resolved. Are you using the built in auth system too? It's driving me crazy...